Knife Project, bad result
I'm trying to cut a round entrance into the sphere. Knife Project results in jagged edges. How does one fix this?



hello, maybe what you want is use X (Delete) > Faces Only?

Once you've done your Knife Project operation, don't delete the vertices, instead press X (Delete) > Faces Only.
